# How to show that there isn't an absolute minimum/maximum for a $f(x,y)$ function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-writing, maxima-minima

I'm dealing with this function $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{(x-a)^2+y^2+4} +\frac{1}{(x+a)^2+y^2+4}$ where $a$ is some constant.

I have realized that it attains it's maximum value at $(x,y)=(0,0)$ ,and that there isn't an absolute minimum since the function will keep attaining smaller values as we plug in higher/smaller values for $(x,y)$ and $a$.

How does one show this formally by using Weierstrass theorem?

Edit:
The Weierstrass theorem was not relevant because the domain of $f(x,y), D$ isn't bounded.

Now I have assumed that the function attains it's absolute minimum $f(x,y)=m$ at $(x,y)=(x_0,y_0)$, so

$m\leq f(x,y) ,\forall(x,y)\Rightarrow \lim_{(x,y)\to\infty} m\leq \lim_{(x,y)\to\infty} f(x,y) \Rightarrow m\leq0.$

Now i want to show that $f(x,y)$ is always positive,I need help in proving that the function attains it's maximum at $(0,0)$.

Comment: The weierstrass theorem is not relevant here if the domain is the entire plane. Can you show it's always positive? Can you find specific inputs that make it arbitrarily small?

Comment: So Weierstrass theorem isn't relevant here ,I did not show that function is always positive but it appears to be ,what do i get from that?

Comment: If it's always positive, then if it had a minimum, it would have to be some positive number. So if you can also show it gets smaller than any positive number, it can't have a minimum.

Comment: Can you demonstrate how this is done in my case?, $f(x,y)=1/2$ when $(x,y)=(0,0),a=0$ how do i go on and show that this will keep getting smaller than $1/2$

Comment: (Assuming $a=0$) you've found an input that makes the output 1/2. Can you find an input that makes it (less than or) equal to $1/4$? What about more numbers that get arbitrarily small, like $1/2^n$? Then you have to figure things out for general $a$, but starting with $a=0$ is a good approach. I would recommend editing your thoughts/work into the question when you next get stuck.

Comment: Shouldn't the critical point for $f(x,y)$ be $(a,1/2)$?

Comment: I have edited the question with what I've tried so far, is this correct so far ?

Comment: Can i get some help by proving that the absolute max is $f(0,0)$ please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f$ is strictly positive for all $(x,y)\in{\mathbb R}^2$. On the other hand, letting $r:=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ we obviously have $\lim_{r\to\infty} f(x,y)=0$. It follows that $f$ assumes no global minimum on ${\mathbb R}^2$.

Let $\epsilon:={1\over2}f(0,0)={1\over a^2+4}>0$. Then there is an $R>0$ such that $f(x,y)\leq\epsilon$ when $r\geq R$. The function $f$ assumes a global maximum $\geq2\epsilon$ on the closed disc $B_R$, and this maximum is then also the global maximum of $f$ on ${\mathbb R}^2$. Furthermore we can assert that this maximum will be taken in an interior point of $B_R$, hence at a critical point of $f$.

Inspection of the  expression defining $f$ shows that at the maximum point we necessarily have $y=0$. It is therefore sufficient to consider the critical points of the function
$$g(x):=f(x,0)={1\over(x-a)^2+4}+{1\over(x+a)^2+4}\ .$$
The numerator of $g'(x)$ computes to
$$N(x)=-4x\bigl(x^4+2x^2(4+a^2)+(4+a^2)(4-3a^2)\bigr)\ .$$
Analyzing the expression on the RHS we find the following: When $a\leq2/\sqrt{3}$ then there is only the critical point $x_0=0$ of $g$, which then necessarily gives the global maximum of $f$ on ${\mathbb R}^2$. But when $a>2/\sqrt{3}$ there are three critical points $x_{\pm1}$ and $x_0$. The graph of $g$ has two local maxima at $x_{\pm1}$ and a local minimum at $x_0=0$. The global maximum of $f$ on ${\mathbb R}^2$ is then given by $f(x_{\pm1},0)$. (The maximal value of $f$ can be explicitly computed.)

[image]

Comment: A bit unrelated but can you please explain to me how the graph of $f(x,y)$ changes according to the value of $a$